# set asp.net session variable from an html input element?

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net

I have a form with an asp.net control button that has a postbackurl. I am setting a session variable via a postback (to same page) from a dropdownlist and then I retrieve that session variable when the page is redirected to the postbackurl when clicking the button.

Problem is, I need to add a search feature to this page also. I cannot use an asp.net textbox control because of design issues in the clients page.

Is it possible to use an html input element and capture the typed value, and store it in an asp.net session variable on button click so I can retrieve it in another page?

I am using this code in page_load of the code-behind, of the page that has the search box (first page)

```
        PostBackOptions postBackOptions = new PostBackOptions(SearchButton);
        postBackOptions.ActionUrl = "/searchdesc";
        SearchButton.Attributes.Add("onclick",
        Page.ClientScript.GetPostBackEventReference(postBackOptions));
```

Is it possible to store a session variable in something like that? I have also tried using AJAX but It doesnt redirect on click.

Any help?

Comment: The point of session variables is that they persist between pages so you should be able to achieve what you are trying to do with them

Answer (score 0):

You can create any HTML input and add an attribute of `runat="server"` and set an `ID` also for that member, then you can attach your event handler if you wish and catch whatever value you need in the code behind.

HTML example:

```
<input type="text" id="yourCustomInput" runat="server" OnClick="YourCustomMethod" />
```

Code behind:

```
protected void YourCustomMethod(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
  //your custom code 
}
```

Comment: First of all, an onclick in an input element? Your answer has nothing to with session variables

Comment: As your question shows, that you primarily have a problem with using another asp `TextBox`, however you can set your session variable in the code behind an use it wherever you want
`// on event set your Session["session"] = "value" ;`
if I didn't got your question correctly in the first place, no problem I can delete the answer. Thanks.